# Mensagem do "required" PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Tenho o seguinte cenário :

```
<h:form id="formValor">

   <p:growl id="growlMessage" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"  showSummary="false" />
   <p:tabView id="tabViewVinculo" dynamic="true" widgetVar="tabViewVinculo"...>
       <p:tab id="tab1">
              <p:input id="inputValue" value="{beam.valor}" required="true" />
       </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="tab1=2">
              <p:input id="inputValue2" value="{beam.valor2}"/>
       </p:tab>

   <p:commandButton id="buttonConfirmar" value="Submit" process="@form" validateClient="true" update="growlMessage" .../>
</form>
```

Tendo este cenário gostaria de personalizar a mensagem exibida no growl que vem da seguinte forma:

"formValor:inputValue: Erro de validação: o valor é necessário."

OBS: Não gostaria de ter mudar o componente "p:growl" para "p:message"

**Considerando tab 2 ativa****

Answer (score 3):

Basta usar o `requireMessage` do componente:

```
<p:inputText id="inputValue" requiredMessage="SUA MENSAGEM" value="{beam.valor}" required="true" />
```

Comment: Não funciona @Rafael, Este "requiredeMessage" só esta funcionando em campos que tenha 'validator="#{bean.validarIdade}" '

Comment: Esse input que você postou no seu código está correto?

Comment: na verdade meu cenário e um pouco mais complexo... editei a pergunta.

Comment: Se ele não está funcionando é por dois motivos, pode ser que o input não está sendo processado ou o valor dele não é vazio.

Comment: Olá @Rafael, obrigado pela atenção segue aqui minha solução.     blogs.oracle.com/johnc/entry/more_jsf_validation_custom_error

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso, eu colocaria o `growl` como `globalOnly="true"` e adicionaria as mensagens diretamente do Bean:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
         FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,     
         "Erro!",
         "Informe um valor para input1."));
```

Comment: Obrigado, eu fiz isto, porém hoje mudei para ficar de uma forma melhor digamos mais elegante já que se trata de uma validação client-side. Segue link : https://blogs.oracle.com/johnc/entry/more_jsf_validation_custom_error           @info.sistemas

Comment: Neste caso, a mudança não é apenas para o cenário apontado, mas para todo o sistema.

Comment: Sim, é verdade mas acredito ter uma melhor apresentação por não utilizar growl para validações client-side, mas que neste caso em que tenho tabview é será submetida todo form apresentar a mensagem que existe campos obrigatórios nulos era necessário utilizar o growl.